# Using PostgreSQL, how do I escape "\" in json columns?

Tags: json, postgresql, escaping, jsonb

I'm using Postgres 9.5 and I have a column ("info") of type 'json'... I'm trying to do this insert:

```
INSERT INTO table ( info )
VALUES (
  '{"entry":"((\+)[0-9]+)"}'
)
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Escape sequence "\+" is invalid.
```

It's interpreting `\+` as an escape sequence but I actually want that as part of my value.

Comment: Please help get this where it belongs, and flag to migrate this to [dba.se].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general,

- if you have keys and values use [`jsonb_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to construct the object
- if you're writing a literal JSON object to cast from string, then it must be proper; a proper JSON string requires escaping `\`.

## Explanation

PostgreSQL isn't quoting this: it's just the JSON implimentation following [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159).

> A string begins and ends with quotation marks.  All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks, except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F). [... ] So, for example, a string containing only a single reverse solidus character may be represented more compactly as `"\\"`.

So it looks like this in the literal form.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
AS
  SELECT '{"entry":"((\\+)[0-9]+)"}'::jsonb AS info;
```

Dollar-quoting in PostgreSQL requires no-escapes, but it will not help here,

> Notice that inside the dollar-quoted string, single quotes can be used without needing to be escaped. Indeed, **no characters inside a dollar-quoted string are ever escaped**: the string content is always written literally. Backslashes are not special, and neither are dollar signs, unless they are part of a sequence matching the opening tag.

So this will **not** work because `\+` is not a valid string in JSON. It would work if we were not using a json type though.

```
SELECT '{"key":"\"}'::jsonb;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: SELECT '{"key":"\"}'::jsonb;
               ^
DETAIL:  Token ""\"}" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"key":"\"}
```

However, you can use `to_jsonb()` to JSON-escape the strings..

```
SELECT FORMAT( $${%s:%s}$$, to_jsonb(k), to_jsonb(v) )::jsonb
FROM ( VALUES
  ('key', '\' )
) AS t(k,v);
```

But, even this is a bad idea because if you have the keys and values you can use `json_build_object`,

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object( k, v )
FROM ( VALUES
  ('key', '\' )
) AS t(k,v);
```

Comment: This works, as it will get escape the \, however... in the database column, I now have an extra \ for this entry ( i.e. ((\\+)[0-9]+) ) when I retrieve this data. Is there a way to have it return the original, unescaped value?